# Multiple Trust relationships statements AWS CDK Python

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a Role that allows current account to assume the role.
The policy looks like this:

```
        role = Role(
        self,
        "TestRole",
        assumed_by=AccountPrincipal(self.account),
        inline_policies={
            "Auth": PolicyDocument(
                statements=[
                    PolicyStatement(
                        actions=["rds-db:connect"],
                        effect=Effect.ALLOW,
                        resources=[
                            f"arn:aws:rds-db:{self.region}:{self.account}:dbuser:*/auth"]
                    )
                ]
            )
        },
        path="/"
    )
```

Now I need to add additional accounts to the trust relationship. I am trying the following:

```
        role.add_to_principal_policy(self,
                                 statement=PolicyStatement(
                                     effect=Effect.ALLOW,
                                     actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
                                     principals=[AccountPrincipal("xxxxxxxxx")]
                                 )
                                 )
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Role.add_to_principal_policy() got multiple values for argument 'statement'
```

What is the correct way to add additional accounts to the trust relationship using AWS CDK python?

Comment: `add_to_principal_policy` takes a single argument, and you're passing two (passing `self` is incorrect here).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the simplest solution was to use CompositePrincipal:

```
from aws_cdk.iam import AccountPrincipal, CompositePrincipal
```

Then list all accounts for `assumed_by` param:

```
assumed_by=CompositePrincipal(
            AccountPrincipal("xxxxxxxxx"),
            AccountPrincipal("xxxxxxxxx") 
        )
```

Comment: Why not just fix the error in the original code and use the code in the question? passing multiple principals to the `principals` prop is allowed.